# dealloc doesn't seem to release all image memory

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management, allocation

An application I am making keeps running into "Memory Warnings", and eventually crashes. It seems that the memory is not freed when release is called on custom view controller classes I have created whose views have been added as subviews.

Here's an example of my situation:

I have created a view controller with an accompianing .xib (to add a sort of popover/menu that allows the user to select a video to play). A button in the top right hand corner of the screen/app calls a function which allocs a new instance of a videoMenu class I created, then adds it's view as a subview. When the user selects a video, a function is called to hide the popover/menu's view, then releases the instance (before displaying/playing the video). If the menu is "open" and the button is pressed again, I have it set up to act like a close button (hiding and then releasing the menu) ... i.e. it toggles the menu.

If I keep pressing the button, the menu appears, and then hides/releases ... over and over ... which is expected. I have noticed though in Instruments->Allocations that when the release is called, the allocations do not decrease. The allocations just keep increasing as I open/close/open/close/etc., as if the release doesn't actually free up memory. I've added an `NSLog` in the `dealloc` of the menu to ensure that `dealloc` is in fact being called.

I have noticed that if I call `[videoMenu.view removeFromSuperview]` before calling `[videoMenu release]`, the allocation does in fact reduce.

Is `removeFromSuperview` the solution?
Is it necessary?

The .xib file has many `UIImageViews` in it, and I am also wondering if they are the reason that the allocation continually increases (in my example outlined above) ... meaning do the same images just keep getting cached over and over?

Comment: Are you running with Zombies enabled?

Comment: unsure, I am only familiar with how to use Allocations and Leaks.

Comment: I mean, does the scheme you are running have Zombies enabled? It's under Project > Edit Schemes > Run > Diagnostics. Is anything checked on that screen?

Comment: ViewController view retains your videoMenu view since you are adding as subview. UIView class reference - addSubview view: The view to be added. This view is retained by the receiver. After being added, this view appears on top of any other subviews. Discussion: This method retains view and sets its next responder to the receiver, which is its new superview. So you need to removeFromSuperView.

Comment: "Enable Zombie Objects" is not checked. How can this help? (I am unfamiliar with zombie objects) ... tyty!!!

Comment: @ChrisAllinson NSZombie causes memory growth because the zombies are never deallocated.Therefore for iOS apps, use it with iOS Simulator rather than on the device itself. For the same reason, don’t use the Zombies template concurrently with the Leaks instrument. Also look here (search for Zombies and more zombies in this document)  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/_index.html

Comment: @scordova88: What is ARC? How can it help?

Thank you for the advice everyone ... I'll reply again if I run into issues. :D

Comment: ARC stands for Automatic Reference Counting, and it is supposed to automatically handle the memory manage for you.  I dont personally use it, but it affects the type of answer that you will receive.

Comment: @scordova88 - Oh I see. I don't use ARC because I initially thought that I would like to have complete control over what is going on with memory management. If I enable it, will all of my objects be released automatically? Will I have to remove all of the [xxx release] calls? Does it work on every version of iOS?  (I am quite unfamiliar with how automatic reference counting works, and how it will affect the way I code) ... ty

Comment: @ChrisAllinson How ARC works, which iOS version, etc., can't be answered in one comment. You should read ARC guide found on Apple Developer website or watch WWDC 2011 Introduction to ARC session # 323.

Comment: ARC is the best thing to come to Objective-C.  It takes most of the tedium and risk out of memory management.  However, you still need to keep track of what is referencing what, and avoid reference loops.